# NetLogo: distance refering agent

Tags: distance, netlogo

I'm new in NetLogo and this may be a too obvious question, but I don't see how to test if what I am doing is right.

I'm making a selection of an agent of breed1 (turtles) based on its distance to breed2 (crocodiles). I would like the crocodile to choose one turtle randomly from the ones around it, but with a higher probability to be chosen the closer the turtle is. Thus, I am using rnd extension and distance command.

My question is if the distance command is referring to the right agent (i.e. distance between the crocodile and the turtles):

```
ask crocodiles [
   let potential_preys turtles in-radius max_distance
   let selected_prey rnd:weighted-one-of potential_preys [ (1 - ( distance ? / max_distance ) ) ]        
   ask selected_prey [    
     scape
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I get to your question, there is another problem I noticed with your code.

I had never realized this before, but NetLogo's semantics can make it tricky to model actual turtles! (At least when other breeds are involved.)

What I mean by this is that `turtles` refer to all turtles in the model, regardless of their breed. It means that, in your case, `crocodiles` are included in `turtles`, so when you say:

```
let potential_preys turtles in-radius max_distance
```

...crocodiles can be included in the potential preys!

Getting around this is easy enough, though: just choose another name for the breed that represent actual turtles in your model, e.g.:

```
breed [ tortoises tortoise ]
```

And then you can write:

```
let potential_preys tortoises in-radius max_distance
```

And now, for your question regarding `distance`, I think what you want is the distance to [`myself`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself), where `myself` would be the crocodile that is selecting its prey. The `myself` primitive refers to the agent in the "outer" context of the block where you use it, i.e., the "calling" agent.

This gives you something like:

```
let selected_prey rnd:weighted-one-of potential_preys [
  1 - (distance myself / max_distance)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I didn't thought about the turtles detail, indeed... ^^
Anyway it was an example, not the actual name of my breeds, so no problem, but thanks for noticing it!

Regarding the question itself, I also think `myself` will do, so I'll keep it like this, but now with higher confidence :D

Thanks Nicolas!